# Search 16 digits number and replace 7th to 12th digits with x

Tags: notepad++, regex

[image]How to use Notepad++ regular expression to replace the 7th to 12th position of the found 16-digits numeric string in a text file with "x" ?

Example of numeric string to search: `1234567890121234`

Expecting Result: `123456xxxxxx1234`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Steps**:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Find what: `(\d{6})(\d{6})(\d{4})`
3. Replace with: `$1xxxxxx$3`
4. Enable "Wrap around"
5. Search Mode: Regular expression
6. Replace All

**Explanation**:

```
()              # designate substring  
\d{6}           # substring: 6 digits   
\d{4}           # substring: 4 digits  
$1              # place 1st substring here  
$3              # place 3rd substring here
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: Replace dialogue box]

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b\d{6}\K\d{6}(?=\d{4}\b)`
- Replace with: `xxxxxx`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary, avoid to match more digits
\d{6}           # 6 digits
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\d{6}           # 6 digits
(?=             # positie lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \d{4}           # 4 digits
    \b              # word boundary, avoid to match more digits
)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]